# Android, display items as tags in a list

Tags: android, user-interface

Sorry for the basic question, but after a long time searching, I still don't know what to call this...

What do you call the list of items to display like this picture, (the addresses in the to section), each item is in a tag, and they will fill up the screen according to the screen size and content of the item.

[image]

I want to search about how to do this in the best way, but I'm not sure what to search for. What are these "tags" called?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as `Chips` . This component represent complex entities in small blocks, such as a contact/email address etc.

I'm attaching a [Material design link](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html#) where you can explore detailed information about them, their types and behaviour.

Comment: Thats what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below libraries to achive it.

https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput

https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips